# OBD II with STM32

Tags: stm32f4discovery, can-bus, obd-ii

I want to make an OBD II Reader using my stm32f4 discovery board. I googled for the some documentations on what kind of CAN frame needs to be sent to the OBD port and what is been received from it. Please help me in this context, I don't want to use an OBD-UART converter like ELM3xx. Suggest me some library or example on STM32F4 platform.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

While STM32f4 supports CAN in hardware, it still needs a CAN transceiver IC, and there are many available on the market (such as [MCP2551](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010405)).

You can find an example of how to use the CAN bus on your board [here](https://github.com/k-code/stm32f4-examples/blob/master/Task-8-US/inc/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_can.c).

After handling the low-level CAN operations in your code, you might want to integrate it with an OBD library, like [ArduinoOBD](https://github.com/stanleyhuangyc/ArduinoOBD/tree/master/libraries/OBD), although you will need to implement some modifications in order to get it working.

Also, a **very** extensive guide for using CAN bus with the discovery board may be [found here](http://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt_236.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

you can find elm327 src code for stm32 at

[ELM327 OBDII STM32](https://github.com/ARoozitalab/ELM327-OBDII-STM32)

this source support  ISO 9141-2(serial) and ISO 15765(can)
and use hc-05 as bluetooth module

Comment: This is not the source-code running in elm327 clones - there are no AT-commands (supported by all ELM327 devices).  So what is this code?  The README is not illuminating at all :-(